# Как реализовать такое на jQuery?

Tags: jquery, анимация, animate

Всем привет. Наткнулся на этот сайт https://kin.movie/#/Explore/, после проигрывания отрезков фильма (есть звук), появляется фон http://prntscr.com/l6ijwl - понравилось его поведение, реакция на мышку и вращение. 
Подскажите, как такое реализовать? Может или пример кода, или плагин какой используется jquery? 
Спасибо

p.s. Может кто спрашивал уже тут, не нашел. Да и чесно говоря, не знаю как правильно это описать для поиска)))

Comment: сайт тормозит со страшной силой ....вот эффектов напихали ...

Comment: у меня не тормозит, выглядит круто. про jquery забудьте, тут d3.js

Comment: тут используетсья GSAP  или TweenMax такие анимации не делаетсья с помощью jQuery.Забудте про jQuery сейчас ера GSAP Three.js SVG если хотите такое й сайт.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Будем разбираться тогда с three.js  и усовершенствуем идейку в итоге))